# Error when instantiating object from model class

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I've hit a snag. On my Summary page I want to pull from a table, YearSummariesStatic, as well as a view, YearSummariesDynamic. I have everything working fine with just the Static table. But I'm getting an error when I try to add Dynamic and I haven't been able to resolve it.

```
Index.cshtml.cs
using Alpha.Data;
using Alpha.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions;

namespace Alpha.Pages {
    public class IndexModel : PageModel {
        private AlphaContext context;

        public IEnumerable<YearSummary> YearSummariesStatic { get; set; }
            =Enumerable.Empty<YearSummary>();

        public IndexModel(AlphaContext ctx) {
            context = ctx;
        }

        public void OnGet() {
            YearSummariesStatic = context.YearSummariesStatic.OrderByDescending(s => s.Year);
        }
    }
}

Index.cshtml
@page
@model Alpha.Pages.IndexModel
@using Alpha.Models;

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm text-center">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (YearSummary s in Model.YearSummariesStatic) {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/Years/@s.Year">@s.Year</a></td>
                <td>@s.League</td>
                <td>@if (@s.League is not null)
                    @s.LeagueRecord</td>
                <td>@s.RegularSeasonRecord</td>
                <td>@if (@s.PostSeasonRecord != "0-0")
                        @s.PostSeasonRecord</td>
                <td>@s.FullSeasonRecord</td>
                <td>@s.HeadCoach</td>
                <td>@s.Notes</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

AlphaContext.cs
using Alpha.Data.Configuration;
using Alpha.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Alpha.Data {
    public class AlphaContext : DbContext {
        #nullable disable
        public AlphaContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {
        }
        #nullable restore

        public DbSet<YearSummary> YearSummariesStatic { get; set; }
//      public DbSet<YearSummary> YearSummariesDynamic { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GameSummary> GameSummaries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OpponentSummary> OpponentSummaries { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new YearSummaryConfiguration());
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new GameSummaryConfiguration());
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new OpponentSummaryConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine with this code. However, when I uncomment the YearSummariesDynamic line in AlphaContext, I get a run time error:

SqlException: Invalid object name 'YearSummary'

on this line in Index.cshtml:

@foreach (YearSummary s in Model.YearSummariesStatic) {

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally, one DbSet maps one table in the database. Do you want to use the YearSummary table to correspond to the two dbset data sets of YearSummariesStatic and YearSummariesDynamic? Can you provide more related configurations about YearSummaryConfiguration?

Comment: @YuningDuan Yes, both tables have the same layout, so I wanted to use the YearSummary model for both of them. Do I need to set up two separate configuration files?

Comment: "Note that DbSet does not support MEST (Multiple Entity Sets per Type) meaning that there is always a one-to-one correlation between a type and a set.": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#remarks  Even if the structure is the same, you'll want to create another model/type named "YearSummariesDynamic".  IF you actually need another DB table for that.  You had said "view" there, so you could just create a class object in the controller to use as a View Model.

Comment: Thank you @pcalkins. So I need duplicate configuration.cs files and duplicate model.cs files. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me if I'm wanting to use the same data structure multiple times.

As far as my use of the word "view", that was in the context of a SQL view, not an MVC view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During a database migration, EF Core will attempt to create a migration for each DbSet that maps to a database table. Because two DbSets reference the same entity type, EF Core may encounter mapping conflicts and not be able to determine how to create a corresponding table for both DbSets.
To avoid these issues, you can use different entity types for two DbSets in the AlphaContext, even if the two entity types have the same properties. You can do this by setting YearSummaryStatic and YearSummaryDynamic to be two derived classes of YearSummary, you can create these two classes and use inheritance to do so, here's an example you can use as a reference:

```
public class YearSummary
{
      
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string League { get; set; }
    public string LeagueRecord { get; set; }
    public string RegularSeasonRecord { get; set; }
    public string PostSeasonRecord { get; set; }
    public string FullSeasonRecord { get; set; }
    public string HeadCoach { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

        
}

public class YearSummaryStatic : YearSummary
{
        
}

public class YearSummaryDynamic : YearSummary
{

}
```

AlphaContext：

```
public class AlphaContext : DbContext
{
    public AlphaContext(DbContextOptions<AlphaContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<YearSummaryStatic> YearSummariesStatic { get; set; }
    public DbSet<YearSummaryDynamic> YearSummariesDynamic { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new YearSummaryStaticConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new YearSummaryDynamicConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Configuration :

```
public class YearSummaryStaticConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<YearSummaryStatic>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<YearSummaryStatic> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("YearSummariesStatic");
        
    }
}



public class YearSummaryDynamicConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<YearSummaryDynamic>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<YearSummaryDynamic> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("YearSummariesDynamic");
        
    }
}
```

After the configuration is complete, I will generate two tables with the same structure:[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you very much. The derived classes with inheritance was the part I was overlooking, makes more sense to me now.